# Exponential distribution and numerical errors?

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, numerical-value

I am working on the measure of a Curie Weiss model over a lattice

$$
\mu[m] = \frac{e^{\beta N (hm + m^2)}}{\sum_z e^{\beta N (hz + z^2)}}\binom{N}{\frac{(1-m)N}{2}}2^{-N}
$$

where $m\in\{-1,-1+2/N,\ldots,1-2/N,1\}$.

I would like to plot moments of the distribution for some largish, fixed, $N$ between $50$ and $200$ vs. $\beta$ between $1.1$ and $150$, in particular I would like to compute 
$
Cov(X,X^2)
$
and 
$
V(X)
$ (i.e. a measure of skewness of this distribution and a measure of variability).

I have the following code

```
g = 1;
\[Iota][m_, n_] := Binomial[n, n*(1 - m)/2]*2^(-n);
f[m_, h_, b_, g_, n_] := (h*m + g/2*m^2) + 
   1/(b*n)*Log[\[Iota][m, n]];
\[Mu][m_, h_, b_, g_, n_] := 
  Exp[-b*n*f[m, h, b, g, n]]/
   Sum[Exp[-b*n*f[x, h, b, g, n]], {x, -1 + 2/n, 1 - 2/n, 2/n}];
moment[h_, x_, b_, g_, n_] := 
  moment[h, x, b, g, n] = 
   Sum[m^x*\[Mu][m, h, b, g, n], {m, -1 + 2/n, 1 - 2/n, 2/n}];
var[h_, b_, g_, n_] := moment[h, 2, b, g, n] - moment[h, 1, b, g, n]^2;
cov[h_, b_, g_, n_] := 
  moment[h, 3, b, g, n] - moment[h, 1, b, g, n]*moment[h, 2, b, g, n];
```

but looking at various plot or values of

$$
Cov(X,X^2)+2V(X)
$$
either the plot has sometimes erratic behavior (changes in behavior for one specific value of N) and trying to compute the value throws an error

[image]

it seems the exponential in this computation are too large.

1) Plotting throws no error, can I trust the plot in anyway?

2) How can I work with this in mathematica?

EDIT 2:
Here's an example with parameter numbers:

```
h=-0.3;
g=1;
n=100;
Table[-b*(cov[h, b, g, n] + 2 var[h, b, g, n])], {b,   1.1, 100}]
```

EDIT 1: One option I considered is to use the following measure

$$
\mu[m] = \frac{e^{\beta N (hm + m^2)-\beta N \bar{f}}}{\sum_z e^{\beta N (hz + z^2)-\beta N \bar{f}}}\binom{N}{\frac{(1-m)N}{2}}2^{-N}
$$

with an appropriate $\bar{f}$, which gives me the same probability but should be more stable numerically. Doing some experiments it seems Mathematica stopped throwing precision error.

But I would like some reassurances: can I rely on mathematica simplifying the exponent first and carry out the calculation later?

Comment: Can you please give example parameters and a concrete call to your functions that results in this warning, so that the reader does not need to speculate?